# Ease from 1 div to show another

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble using the ease function in CSS.
I have an image and when you hover over it I want it to ease to get bigger and show another div.

```
<div class="info1">
      <img src="info.png">
      <div class="infoh">
        <p>Information to be shown when hovered over</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS

```
.infoh {
 width: 180px;
 height: 180px;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #ffb534;
 padding: 30px;
 border-radius: 100%;
-moz-border-radius: 100%;
-webkit-border-radius: 100%;
 border: 4px solid #ffffff;
 z-index: 1;
 margin-left: -80px;
 margin-top: -33px;
 }

.infoh p {
font-size: inherit;
text-align: center;
}

.info1:hover .infoh {
 display: block;
}

.info1 {
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 margin-left: 19.5%;
 margin-top: -1.5%
 }
```

I tried placing it on the image but that didn't work, then I tried on each div, and couldn't get it to ease. It just pops up.

```
.info1 img {
 -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari */
 transition: width 2s;
 transition-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

Comment: You can't transition the `display:property....that's why.

Comment: I'd suggest you try `visibility` and `opacity` [**article link**](http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure of the effect you're after, but as @Paulie_D said, you're probably looking at using `visibility` and `opacity`.

Here's some code to try out, and at least that should give you something to work with.
(I also changed the order of your HTML a bit)

```css
.info1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
 }

.info1 img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  
  -webkit-transition: all 2s; /* Safari */
  transition: all 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.infoh {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #ffb534;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff;
  
  -webkit-transition: all 1s; /*Safari*/
  transition: all 1s;
 }

.infoh p {
  font-size: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

.info1:hover img {
  width: 300px; 
  height: 300px;
}

.info1:hover .infoh {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s; /*Safari*/
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="info1">
  <div class="infoh">
    <p>Information to be shown when hovered over</p>
  </div>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
</div>
```

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: This worked! The only problem I'm running into now is that it works on every browser, except when in safari on the iPhone, only 3 of the 5 divs I am using it on work.

Comment: Can you post a link here, and I'll check out the code? Or put it in something like codepen.io.

If it works 3 out of 5 times, then it might just be a typo or something easy to fix :)

Comment: Looks like you got it sorted?